# HTML: semantically mark up an address?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

How do I mark up an address (e.g. a listing of businesses and their addresses)? The problem is that I won't always have enough address information to complete a vCard microformat. The `address` HTML tag is supposed to be contact information for the author of the page, so probably not the correct tag to use.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if it's a *list* of businesses and their addresses, perhaps you should use a list. There isn't a semantic element for every possible thing you could do in HTML, you just have to use the one that is most relevant. Depending on how you're going to be formatting this information, you should use either a table if the data is in a tabular format, or a list for pretty much any other format.

You can style the list to remove the bullets at the side, but the bottom line is you're still providing a *list* of data, and that's the most semantic thing you could use.

Comment: Each business will be a list item. I want to know how to mark up just the address part (there are other details about the business that I need to provide to the user, not just the address).

Comment: You'll just have to put it in a span. It's still a part of the data list, just with separate focus from the rest of the data for that list item.

Comment: Why not a <p> tag? Or perhaps a list (each address line is an item in the list)? There must be a "standard" way to mark up an address. I can't be the first one facing this problem.

Comment: It wouldn't be semantically correct to put a paragraph inside a list. You could make each item in the list another list if you wanted too, I don't see any problems with that semantically.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure on what exactly your asking, but if it's from a search engine point of view your worried about give Schema.org a go. There is some great info and example on [the local business page](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) to help you markup the address for search engines.

Comment: Plus, don't panic about using an address element for it. HTML5 elements are meant to be versatile and what you feel should be in them. To me, address looks like the right element to use in this situation, and who can penalise you for that.

Comment: I'm not concerned with search engines. Just want to get the mark up right. I'm not using HTML5. I want the solution to work for HTML5 and earlier. The link you provided runs into the same problem as vCard: what to do when not all address elements are available?

Comment: @blameembrey I disagree with your comment. The specification explicitly states that `<address>` should be used only to represent **contact information for the article or document author**. One shouldn't just go ahead and use elements as one wishes for any reason; that's why specs exist. I think your original answer is correct, that for now the best bet is to use the Schema.org `PostalAddress` itemtype with the `address` or `location` itemprops. The element should be `<p>` if standalone, `<li>` if in a list, `<td>` if in a table, etc.

Comment: @chharvey These comments are almost 5 years old, but I still think it's valid. If you wanted to mark something up for programmatic access, you would probably be looking at the JSON-LD or microdata specifications. If the addresses are related to the primary content on the page, you can use the `<address>` element. That comment wasn't meant to mean do whatever you want, it's the wild west - but I can see today how it looks like that. So yes, use the element that is semantically valid for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no designated element for marking up a physical address or postal address. You are correct: `<address>` should be used only to represent contact information for the article or document author, so you should not use it to mark up the addresses in a listing of businesses for example.

When HTML doesn’t exist for certain semantics, your best bet is to mark up the element closest in meaning, and then use auxiliary standards such as (1) Microformat classes, (2) Microdata attributes, and/or (3) ARIA roles. Personally I prefer Microdata over Microformats because Microdata doesn’t interfere with the `[class]` attribute, which is meant for styling. I don’t like to mix semantics with style. ARIA roles are for accessibility and I don’t know enough about them to say much, but they are very good to have in your code.

Read up on the [Microdata syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/) (an extension to HTML). Microdata is the official *syntax* in markup, whereas Schema.org is a very popular (Google loves it) *vocabulary* to use with the syntax. There are other less-popular vocabularies as well.

To mark up a physical address, use the [Schema.org PostalAddress](http://schema.org/PostalAddress) itemtype, with its corresponding properties. Honestly the best element to use would be a plain old `<p>`.

```
<p itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
  <span itemprop="name">The White House</span>
  <br/>
  <span itemprop="streetAddress">1600 Pennsylvania Avenue</span>
  <br/>
  <span itemprop="addressLocality">Washington</span>,
  <span itemprop="addressRegion">DC</span>
  <span itemprop="postalCode">20500</span>
  <br/>
  <data itemprop="addressCountry" value="US">United States of America</data>
  <br/>
  <span itemprop="url">https://www.whitehouse.gov/</span>
</p>
```

The `<br/>` element is meant to provide (semantic, meaningful) line breaks in content, so its use is justified here in a postal address. It’s also an extremely conventional use case. However it can be argued that a `<pre>` works just as well, as it is technically preformatted text.

```
<pre itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
  <span itemprop="name">The White House</span>
  <span itemprop="streetAddress">1600 Pennsylvania Avenue</span>
  <span itemprop="addressLocality">Washington</span>, <span itemprop="addressRegion">DC</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">20500</span>
  <data itemprop="addressCountry" value="US">United States of America</data>
  <span itemprop="url">https://www.whitehouse.gov/</span>
</pre>
```